# How to set launch arguments for Cocoa App in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I want my app to be launched from Xcode with specified command-line arguments. But I cannot find how to specify them.
Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are start and stop buttons in the left top corner of the main window.
Dropdown menu with the name of project stands right next to it. 
Click to it and select "Edit Scheme" menu item.
Scheme editor window appears. Click the "Run" item in left sidebar and see "Arguments" tab in right pane of this window.